# Quickly Find Value in One Column, Change Value in Another

Tags: ms-access, lookup

So I made a little mistake when I initially setup on of my Access tables and need help fixing it (as easily as possible).

I have one table called `Locations` (small table, 10s of rows) and another called `Encounter Data` (large table, 100,000s rows).  The `Encounter Data` has a lookup column that points to `Locations`.

My mistake I made was to store the location *name* and not its primary key in the `Encounter Data` column.  Now, obviously, if I make a change in the `Locations` table to the name of a particular item, the lookup in `Encounter Data` fails.  What I should have down was store the Primary Key (then I can edit all the `Locations` information freely).

I am to fix that.

But I am not sure how to go about inserting the correct ID in a new column in place of the name.

My thought was to simply add a new column, create the lookup correctly (store the primary key), and then to either: [1] sort my `Encounter Data` by location and do a quick-drag/auto-fill like I would in excel to match up the correct IDs with the stored names or [2] do  a find/replace ... only find a value in `LocationWhoopsColumn` and enter the correct ID in the `LocationCorrectColumn`.

But neither of these methods seems feasible.  I have very few location but a lot of rows to fix ... how do I do this quickly?  Manually changing row-by-row would take hours if not days.

Thanks!~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the new column `LocationId` in `Encounter Data` and then run

```
UPDATE [Encounter Data] a INNER JOIN Locations b ON a.LocationName = b.Name
SET a.LocationId = b.id
```

check the results and then drop column LocationName when satisfied.

Comment: I have to wait to Monday (back at work) to try these answers out; will have to pick which one worked best then.  Thanks!

Comment: Worked great - was very slow (took an hour or more) but did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"*... find a value in LocationWhoopsColumn and enter the correct ID in the LocationCorrectColumn*"

Use `DLookup` to retrieve the primary key value from `Locations` based on matching the location name field to `LocationWhoopsColumn`.

```sql
UPDATE YourBigTable
SET LocationCorrectColumn =
    DLookup(
        "pkey",
        "Locations",
        "location_name ='" & LocationWhoopsColumn & "'");
```

I guessed "pkey" and "location_name" as `Locations` field names; replace with your real names.

That UPDATE may not be fast, but hopefully that won't be a deal breaker since you need do this one time only.

Comment: The 1st suggestion worked for me, so I never got to try yours.  I've used DLookup in VBA ... didn't think of applying it to SQL (which is because I know 0.1% of anything about SQL).  Thanks.